# Не запускается *.bat файл node.js. *.exe = запускается

Tags: node.js

Пытаюсь запустить .bat файл через ноду, но не запускается, виснет консоль.
А если запускать .exe файл = его запускает и консоль сразу завершает работу скрипта, как запустить *.bat файл?

```
// Так не запускает файл и виснет консоль
cp.execFile('C:/dir/m.bat', function(err, data) {  
    console.log(err)
    console.log(data.toString());                       
}); 

// Так работает, запускает нотпад
cp.execFile('C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe', function(err, data) {  
    console.log(err)
    console.log(data.toString());                       
});
```

Содержимое m.bat (банальное переименование папки с 222 на 333)

```
rename 222 333
pause
```

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_spawning_bat_and_cmd_files_on_windows

Answer (score 1):

Очень подозреваю что так:

```
cp.execFile('C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe',['C:/dir/m.bat'], function(err, data) {  
  console.log(err)
  console.log(data.toString());                       
});
```